# Is there an "easy" way to migrate ASP.NET MVC pages/files to a strict Angular structure?

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

I'm a relative newbie to both Angular 6 and a complete newbie to ASP.NET MVC (although I've been a developer for many years and have some prior C# experience).  We have a mature Angular 6 project (using Material components with a Java RESTful backend) that is in production and is working well.  We are looking to integrate a series of pages/features from an ASP.NET MVC/Angular 7 project (using Razor, Routing, WebPack and PrimeNg components) that was developed by another team.

I understand that content for the ASP.NET MVC pages is generated on the server and then sent to the client.  Where, the Angular project is calling HTTP endpoints to render the pages locally.

Is there a well documented process for migrating the ASP.NET MVC pages/structure (.cshtml) to a more strict Angular structure (.html/.ts)?  Or, am I looking at rewriting the ASP.NET pages from scratch?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As far as I know they have to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite pages of ASP.NET MVC to Angular components. Because ASP.NET MVC uses C# and Angular uses JavaScript.

Some guidelines:

- Partial views can be used as reusable component
- use Web API

In addition, while rewriting you can see  [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) as a best practice of writing Angular application.